# ui-router Is there a way to reload a certain state without reloading the whole page?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Let's say I have the following three states: `root`, `accounts` and `accounts.edit`.

Accounts will be just a list of account names (for the sake of the exercise) and `accounts.edit` will be a simple input with a submit button that updates the account name. They are both children of the `root` state.

I want the account names to reload after I save the selected account and to this end i've tried using `$state.go('accounts', {}, {reload: true});` and while it does reload the account list, it also reloads the whole page (in this case the rest of the page is just the `root` state that has a simple navigation control).

Is there a way for me to reload just the `accounts` state without also reloading `root`?

Answer (score 0):

It would have to hierarchical, i.e:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('root', { ... })
    .state('root.accounts', {...})
    .state('root.accounts.edit', {...});
```

Though if the navigation stuff isn't ever going to change, you might want to move it out of the state views entirely, i.e:

```
...
<body ng-app="MyApp">
   <!-- nav goes here -->
   <div ui-view></div>
</body>
```

Comment: The navigation stuff will change as it will hide elements you don't have access to. Anyway, I actually changed the way my program works so it no longer requires the states to be refreshed individually. I use a service for my accounts list and just refresh the service after changing an account. The question still stands tho.

Comment: I should have been more clear, when I said doesn't change, I meant from the standpoint that it isn't replace with something else. I have a similar set up where I show/hide login vs dash buttons.

Comment: can u provide a working example on how to reload root.accounts' controller without initializing root's controller?